# Assign alphabets in Numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to assign alphabets in to numbers. When I print 1 I want to get "a". I tried many codes.  Please help me to get out of this issue.

```
characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
d = {}
for x in range(len(characters)):
    d[characters[x]] = x+1
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: If you want to translate _numbers to letters_, your dict needs to map _number keys_ to _letter values_.

Answer (score 1):

Your `characters` string is most of the way to being a solution all on its own.  If you add an extra character to the start of the string (to take up the `0` space), you can just use the number as the index into the string:

```
>>> characters = ' abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> characters[1]
'a'
```

Comment: Or just use zero-based indexing, like a normal person :)

Comment: I assume the intent is to use this to implement a specific cipher; mapping 1...26 to A...Z is usually the cipher you teach to someone who's learning the concept for the first time.  :)

Comment: @Samwise. Zero based indexing is an even more fundamental concept.

Comment: @MarkRansom. Not at all, only that normal people use zero based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up the keys and the values in your dictionary. Since you want to look up letters using integer indices, you want to use the index as the key and the letter as the value, not the other way around:

```py
d = {}
for x in range(len(characters)):
    d[x + 1] = characters[x]

print(d[1])
```

This outputs:

```py
a
```